# What is the difference between "He is planning to build a rockery" and "He is planning building a rockery."

Tags: meaning, difference, phrases

-**He is planning to build a rockery.**

-**He is planning building a rockery.**

What's the difference between the two sentences?

What do the two sentences mean?

Comment: For the second one, it should be "He is planning **on** building a rockery."

Comment: The difference is the second sentence is ungrammatical. If you wanted to keep the gerund form use a conjunction: “He is planning **and** building a rockery.” It's grammatical and with more context it would make logical sense. Someone might object as to how you can plan and build something contemporarily.

Answer (score 0):

The second does not follow standard English grammar. As for meaning it could mean either that he is performing preparatory steps to creating a rockery or that he intends at some point to create a rockery. Without further information it is not possible to tell which is the case.